# why is strtof is always evaluating to HUGE_VAL?

Tags: c

What could be the issue here? It doesn't matter what number I choose for str, it is always 26815615859885194199148049996411692254958731641184786755447122887443528060147093953603748596333806855380063716372972101707507765623893139892867298012168192.00

```
char *str = "2.6";
printf("%f\n", strtof(str, (char**)NULL));
//prints 26815615859885194199148049996411692254958731641184786755447122887443528060147093953603748596333806855380063716372972101707507765623893139892867298012168192.00
```

whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = "2.6";
    printf("%f\n", strtof(str, NULL));
    return 1;
}
```

compile with -Wall:

```
test4.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function âstrtofâ
```

Comment: It works fine here; are you building in some unusual way?

Comment: Check what `NULL` is defined as.  It shouldn't have been redefined, but...  Also, try passing in `((void *)0)` and `0` instead of `(char**)NULL` for the 2nd argument.

Comment: post literally the entire file *test4.c*.

Comment: %f is for floats, you're giving it a string.

Comment: @artefacto, left that part out, it's added now.

Comment: @bstullkid -- you should return 0 instead of 1.  A non-zero return from main is typically taken to mean that an error occurred during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What platform are you building for/on?  The warning that you say is being emitted:

```
test4.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function âstrtofâ
```

indicates that the compiler doesn't know that `strtof()` returns a float, so it's going to push an `int` to the `printf()` call instead of a `double`.  `strtof()` is normally declared in `stdlib.h`, which you're including. But it wasn't a standard function until C99, so the exact compiler platform (and configuration/options you're using) may affect whether it's being made available or not.

Comment: you must use `-std=c99` to use it, or switch to strtod

Answer (score 4):

`strtof` is defined in C99 only. It may be that passing the option `-std=c99` to the compiler will fix it since default GCC (`-std=gnu89`) includes only a few C99 features.

Another option is to use the C89-kosher `strtod`. Which is probably the better option in the long run, anyways. (When do you need singles except in exceptional circumstances?)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you've forgotten to include the correct header(s)?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%f\n", strtof("2.6", NULL));
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
2.600000
```

for me...

Answer (score 3):

Given your warnings, you should try adding -std=c99 to get the C99 standard definitions from the header.  By default it will assume that the return value is an int and then try to convert that to a float.  This will obviously be wrong.  Alternatively you could simply supply your own, correct declaration for strtof().

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, you need -std=c99.  But you can also use strtod() which is string to double, and you don't need -std=c99 for that.

I was having problems with strtof() on CentOS 5.5 with glibc 2.5 unless I used -std=c99, but strtod() worked perfectly.